# Azure Active Directory Application requiredResourceAccess limitation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In one of our projects we are using Azure AD for service-2-service authentication. We set up the AAD Apps/Service Principals via the Azure Active Directory Graph API.

There is one central application that has access to a lot of other microservices. For some reason we are running in an exception when adding more than ~15 requiredResourceAccess entries to the manifest. The error message returned by the Graph API is:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Directory_ResourceSizeExceeded",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value":"The 
 size of the object has exceeded its limit. Please reduce the number of values and retry your req
 uest."},"date":"2018-06-18T03: 37: 45","requestId":"870eef53-c6af-4003-92c3-e1259ac20221","values": [
                {
                    "item": "PropertyName",
                    "value": "requiredResourceAccess"
                },
                {
                    "item": "PropertyErrorCode",
                    "value":"
 QuotaExceeded"}]}}
```

Searching the [web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) brought up that there is a limit when adding extension properties to a directory object. However, we are not using any extension properties in our scenario, just the built-in properties. For larger systems ~15 requiredResourceAccess entries is rather few.

Might this be a limitation of the AAD Graph API over the Microsoft Graph or are we missing something obvious here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please not that there is no limit for resources exist within tenant. However, resources exist in external tenants are capped at 10.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. However, both, the client and consumer aad apps are in the same tenant. Further, it seems that we are not necessarily running into the issue if we have exactly 10 requiredResourceAccess entries. We also saw the issue when we already had 11 or 13 requiredResourceAccess entries. Also, can you please elaborate on what you mean by "external" tenants? Thx